# setting up emacs shells

Tags: emacs, startup

I do this kind of things very often (Every week) in Emacs when I restart it:

1. open a shell connecting to a RSH server, execute some commands, rename the buffer
2. repeat step1 for a few different remote machines

I was thinking: is there a way so that I can hard code these setups in the start-up scripts?

Comment: pretty much anything is possible with emacs. You would need to write a custom function in lisp, and put it in your .emacs file.

Comment: @EdH yeah, I know it should be possible, cause I didn't do EMACs customization a lot, and barely wrote any LISP functions, can you point me some samples of this.

Comment: Do you have to type in a password to connect to your remote servers?

Comment: @Thomas , currently not, what if it is needed, will that make things a lot difficult ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that starts a shell, ssh-es to a host, and runs a command before dropping into an interactive shell:

```
(defun start-remote-shell (host command)
  (shell (format "*shell-%s*" host))
  (sleep-for 0 500)  ; Wait half a second for the prompt to appear
  (insert (format "ssh -t %s %s'; exec bash -i'"
                  (shell-quote-argument host)
                  (shell-quote-argument (shell-quote-argument command))))
  (comint-send-input))
```

You can put this snippet into your `.emacs` file, followed by the specific calls you want, such as:

```
(start-remote-shell "server-one" "apache start")
(start-remote-shell "server-two" "mysql start")
(start-remote-shell "server-three" "foo start")
```

Comment: I am encountering ansi-color-apply-on-region "Marker does not point anywhere"   I did a few search, some suggesting the wait for prompt not long enough, but after I change that to 3 seconds, I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this can help you:

```
(mapc (lambda (server)
    (shell (concat "*shell-" server "*"))
    (insert "ls")
    (comint-send-input)
    (insert "ps ax")
    (comint-send-input))
  '("server1" "server2"))
```

As you can see, with insert write to the console, and with comint-send-input is like hit the return key in the terminal.
In this example a ls and a ps will be execute on two shell buffers